# Passing command-line arguments to an emscripten-generated application

Tags: javascript, emscripten

When a C program is compiled with Emscripten, there is an HTML page generated that will display the results of the program.  I was wondering how you could pass command line arguments to the application.  For instance, with the original C program it's `./bfs 32 1`.

Answer (score 15):

I was able to pass command line arguments by adding a line to the generated .html file. Not sure if this is the correct solution but it worked.
There's a `var Module` declared. simply add the following line underneath: `arguments: ['32', '1'],`