# .js created (by Webassembly and emscripten) works only once

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I'm using Webassembly and emscripten for a project and the webpage is working very well. In it I send a textarea with information to the .js created (by Webassembly and emscripten), for processing, but, oh, there is the problem !!, only works only once, when I modify the which is in the textarea and resubmit to js, ​​it does nothing. When I reload the page it works again (only once).

I'm using this way(found on [Providing stdin to an emscripten HTML program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912129/providing-stdin-to-an-emscripten-html-program)):

I comment run(); in the end of emscript

```
// in my emscript 

// shouldRunNow refers to calling main(), not run().
var shouldRunNow = true;
if (Module['noInitialRun']) {
   shouldRunNow = false;
}
//run(); // << here
// {{POST_RUN_ADDITIONS}}
```

.

```
 result = areaInput(); \\and add areaInput in result
```

add the code below in my file to activate run () in emscript

```
<script>
var message;
var point = -1;
function getArea(){
   message = document.getElementById('input').value.split('\n');
}
function areaInput(){
  if(point >= message.length - 1){
    return null;
  }
  point += 1;
  return message[point];
}
function execEmscript(){
  window.console = {
     log: function(str){
        document.getElementById("output").value += "\n" + str;
    }
 }
getArea();
run();
}
</script>
```

io textareas

```
<textarea id="input" cols="80" rows="30"></textarea>

<textarea id="output" cols="80" rows="30"></textarea>
```

and a button

```
<button onclick="execEmscript();">run</button>
```

Comment: What does `run()` do?

Comment: run () makes the code, which was C ++ and which with webassembly / emscripten turned js, works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe these settings would be helpful:

**from [src/settings.js](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/settings.js):**

```js
// Whether we will run the main() function. Disable if you embed the generated
// code in your own, and will call main() yourself at the right time (which you
// can do with Module.callMain(), with an optional parameter of commandline args).
var INVOKE_RUN = 1;

// If 0, the runtime is not quit when main() completes (allowing code to
// run afterwards, for example from the browser main event loop). atexit()s
// are also not executed, and we can avoid including code for runtime shutdown,
// like flushing the stdio streams.
// Set this to 1 if you do want atexit()s or stdio streams to be flushed
// on exit.
var EXIT_RUNTIME = 0;
```

In your Emscripten version you may have `EXIT_RUNTIME = 1` by default. Other options from that file are interesting, too.

So try to specify `-s INVOKE_RUN=0 -s EXIT_RUNTIME=0` to `emcc` command (you don't need to comment out `run()` then).

But your program may be not expecting that you invoke `main()` multiple times. This probably may be worked around by setting `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS` to export some other C function and call it from your JS (not sure, but you may first need to call `main()`).

Comment: FYI, the linked src/settings.js file seems to have moved: this is a link which works at this moment https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/src/settings.js#L79-L97 (also added an anchor highlighting lines 79..97 which hold the relevant lines referenced above).