# stdin to an emscripten, about how to continue input?

Tags: c, stdin, emscripten

related to  [Providing stdin to an emscripten HTML program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912129/providing-stdin-to-an-emscripten-html-program)

```js
function stdin() {
      if (i < input.length) {
        var code = input.charCodeAt(i);
        ++i;
        return code;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

input.length should be length+2. then stdin will continue, why?

example:

```
function stringToBuffer(value: string): Uint8Array {
  let view = new Uint8Array(value.length);
  for (let i = 0, length = value.length; i < length; i++) {
      view[i] = value.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return view;
}

input = stringToBuffer("123");
i=0;
out();
input = stringToBuffer("xyz");
i=0;
out();
```

c file

```c
int out()
{
   
    int chr;
    while ((chr = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
    {
      fputc(chr, stdout);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: if we set  `i < input.length` ,  the `fputc(chr, stdout);` can not print `input = stringToBuffer("xyz");` . it only print the above one `stringToBuffer("123");`

but if set `i < input.length+2`, it will print all. 123 and xyz.

I guess something related to the native emscripten `stdin` function?

Comment: Update question with clarification instead of a comment (which is good).  I don't know anything about emscripten, btw.  The c function looks ok to me, but it's odd it returns a fixed  value of 1 (that you don't use).  Snippets are usually not a great way to ask for help opposed to a [mre].